# key generation AES encryption symbian

Tags: c++, symbian

I want to create public key for AES key encryption is there are direct APIs in symbian thnx in advance.
  currently i am using the default api.

Answer (score 2):

AES is a symmetric cipher and does not have the notion of public/private keys.

As for the AES key itself, just generate e.g. 256 random bits for AES256. For cryptographically strong random generation, use e.g. `CSystemRandom::GenerateBytesL()`. Include `random.h`, link against `random.lib`.

Comment: PKCS5padding  and  CBC cipher mode  and init vector(IV) how to achieve in AES in symbian

Comment: That's a completely different question from key generation. Please post a new question for that.